# Python Regex Word Boundary with % sign

Tags: python, regex

I want to detect all `1%` as a substring with word boundary. Using following code snipped in python does not return anything. I want to detect first two 1% substrings but not 1% that is part of last word 0.1%. That's why word boundary is important.

```
matches = re.finditer(r'\b1%\b', '1% of 100 is not 1% of 10 its 0.1%', re.I)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

From [python `re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

> Note that formally, `\b` is defined as the boundary between a `\w` and a
> `\W` character (or vice versa), or between `\w` and the beginning or end
> of the string.

observe that digits belong to `\w` and dot belongs to `\W` therefore there is boundary inside`.1` and both `%` and space belong to `\W` therefore there is not boundary inside `%`

You might use negative lookbehind to exclude 1s prefixed with dot as follows

```
import re
matches = re.finditer(r'(?<![.])1%', '1% of 100 is not 1% of 10 its 0.1%', re.I)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

gives output

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='1%'>
<re.Match object; span=(17, 19), match='1%'>
```

Observe that I used `[.]` as literal dot is required, not dot which would mean any character.